# Creating an array with jQuery of object IDs to process on Django backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, arrays

I've got some javascript that is creating an li based on an object returned from the backend after an AJAX search. The user can keep searching for devices and when selected they are added to the current page (as an li). Each time a new li is created, I want to send the id's of the objects that have already been chosen.

When the li's are created, their id's are named "device-###" where ### is the ID of the device in the database, so I need to strip that part out.

Here's the javascript that's giving me problems:

```
        var children = $('#temp_inventory').children();
        var count = children.length;
        var devices = [];
        var i = 0;
        while (i<=count){
            devices[i] = children[i].id.substr(4);
            i++;
        };
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'attr'
```

I also tried it the non-jQuery way:

```
devices[i] = children[i].id.substr(4);
```

And I end up with this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

When I throw in `alert(children[i].id.substr(4));` I get an alert with the number I'm expecting.

Comment: The reason your jQuery version wasn't working is because the `children[i]` returns the *actual element*, not the element wrapped in a jQuery object. The workaround would be `$(children[i]).attr`. #themoreyouknow

Answer (score 4):

Part of the issue is probably that your loop uses `<=` instead of `<`. Remember the last item in a list that uses a zero-based index is `length - 1`.

To create an Array of the IDs, you could use the [`map()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method instead.

```
var devices = $('#temp_inventory').children().map(function() {
    return this.id.substr(4);
}).get();
```

The `.map()` method populates a jQuery object (which is an Array-like object) with the values you *return* in the function.

Then the [`get()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method gives you an Array of those values instead of a jQuery object.

You could also use the [`toArray()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) method which does the same thing.

```
var devices = $('#temp_inventory').children().map(function() {
    return this.id.substr(4);
}).toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want,

```
while (i<count){
  devices[i] = children[i].id.substr(4);
  i++;
};
```

otherwise the last iteration will be beyond the last item in the array.

A more concise way of doing this using [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var devices = $.map($('#temp_inventory').children(), function(elem) {
  return elem.id.substr(4);   
});
```